# Why is it still returning users with the same id in followers array?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

**Express function controller**

```
export const getWhoToFollow = catchAsync(
async (req: Request & AuthRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) =\> {
const id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userData?.id);

    const users = await User.find({
      followers: { $nin: [id] },
      _id: { $ne: id },
    }).limit(3);
    
    res.status(200).json(users);

}
);
```

**Model:**

```
const userSchema: Schema<IUser> = new Schema({
  nick: { type: String, maxLength: 16, default: "" },
  following: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
  followers: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }],
});
```

**Im trying to get 3 users that i dont follow. But it still returning users with my id in their followers array. And when i change it to ( *followers: { $in: [id] }* ), it return empty array.**

Comment: Did you try `console.log(req.userData?.id)` ?

Comment: @AndyRay yea its valid id. I just dont understand why its not working properly :/

Comment: [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/): _If the field holds an array, then the $nin operator selects the documents whose field holds an array with no element equal to a value in the specified array (for example, <value1>, <value2>, and so on)._